# LLVM IR Loading type name mangling

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm having a hard time fixing this problem with loading LLVM-IR modules.

First of all here is the problem.
I have this LLVM-IR File with this instruction:

```
%7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.hoge, %struct.hoge* %6, i32 0, i32 0, !dbg !34
```

Now, when I load it using my tool, it turns to this:

```
%7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.hoge.0, %struct.hoge.0* %6, i32 0, i32 0, !dbg !34
```

My goal is to get rid of this `.0` at the end of all struct types.

Here is some code,

Module loading:

```
Module *FPR_::load(const path &input) const {
    // Construct module
    SMDiagnostic err;
    unique_ptr<Module> module{parseIRFile(input.string(), err, ctx, true, "")};
    ...
```

Module printing:

```
ofstream ofs("hoge.ll");
string str;
raw_string_ostream rso(str);
module->print(rso, NULL, true, true);
ofs << str;
```

Now, let me tell you what I've done so far.

1. I've debugged my instrumentation tool and found out that this `.0` gets added when the module is LOADED not PRINTED. I found this out because my tool outputs some instructions for debug purposed and they already have the `.0`s right after loading.
2. I've tried to load and print the same module multiple times and this is the result.

```
%7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.hoge.0.0.0.0.0.0, %struct.hoge.0.0.0.0.0.0* %6, i32 0, i32 0, !dbg !34
```

Which would be funny if this isn't stopping me from developing my tool.

3. Verified that this does not happen with the `opt` tool.

```
[user@host]opt hoge.ll -o foo.ll
[user@host]diff hoge.ll foo.ll
[user@host]
```

Which means there must be something I'm missing that `opt` does.

4. Read `opt`'s source code.
   Some of the code felt like they mattered. And here is what I've ended up with.

```
LLVMContext ctx;
ctx.setDiscardValueNames(false);
ctx.enableDebugTypeODRUniquing();
FPR_::FPR_ FPR_(path(src_ll.getValue()), path(dep_ll.getValue()), ctx, options); // Module gets loaded in this constructor.
```

The options in the `Context` is all I found that `opt` seemed to do different. But no results so far.

Frankly, I'm out of ideas on how to fix this. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

And as a side note, I know that it is recommended to use the `opt` tool itself for static analysis or instrumentation.
But the problem is, the tool I am trying to make uses the static analysis for dynamic analysis as well. So I do not want my program to end when it outputs the instrumented LLVM-IR.

I could do some dirty hack and not return from the `runOnModule` method and just print the Module from there. But I do want to avoid that if possible.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So, does this happen when your tool is an identity transform (i.e. simply reads and write the IR without changing anything whatsoever)?  If so, could you please provide an absolutely MWE that replicates this behaviour?

Comment: You seem to add that `%struct.hoge` second time somehow.

Comment: @compor Yes. For debugging, I output the code two times in different files. First, right after loading the IR then after instrumenting the IR. Name gets mangled(?) the same. As for the second question, what does MWE stand for?

Comment: @arrowd I’m sorry. I don’t think I’m following what you’re saying. Could you please re-phrase it?

Comment: The LLVM module loader will rename types when it thinks two different types might have the same name. It's a bit too eager for my taste so I patched it, but anyway, what happens is that the type exists, and *then* a module that uses the type is loaded, and the loader assumes that the existing type and the type referenced in the loaded module aren't meant to be the same, and renames one just to be safe.

Comment: @funnypigrun Could you please elaborate, why this is a problem? And why you're relying on the particular naming? Note that names are debugging feature and they could be easily stripped from the module.

Comment: @arnt Thank you. Now I understand why this happens. Is there any way to disable this? Because this does not happen in the `opt` tool on both llvm-project version `9.0.0` and `10-init`. I think `ctx.setDiscardValueName(false)` was supposed to fix it but it's not? Which part of llvm shall I modify?

Comment: @AntonKorobeynikov It's quite complicated. But let's say I have a C source code that I want to analyze. For static analysis, I need debug information of the C code. On the other hand, for dynamic analysis, I need LLVM-IR debug information. Which is obtained by using `-strip-debug` and `-debugify` passes. Now, this means I have 2 LLVM-IR codes that I have to be able to map with each other. (Also, one of them is instrumented) This is where the name mangling becomes a problem, I use string matching to find the same instruction. If there is any alternatives, I would be really happy to hear it.

Comment: The easiest way to fix it is to use two different contexts (one per module), then you won't get collisions. Have you considered this approach?

Comment: @funnypigrun I agree with AlexDenisov.

Comment: Moreover, the whole problem stems from the way you've designed your analyses. Instead of trying to map information from one to another maybe you should reconsider your pipeline design and use the same source twice and correlate the 2 with something that does not change (names at the IR level are quite fragile anyway).

Comment: @AlexDenisov Oh. That explains a lot. So, If I understand correctly, the mangling is caused by two 'mostly' same modules getting loaded with the same context. And the result is that the latter module's type is considered a different one so it gets indexed. I didn't really know what `LLVMContext` was for until now. My tool used to only load one module before I had to take the dynamic analysis into account. Maybe that's why I was getting away with just one context. Thank you very much.

Comment: @compor I suppose my current design could use some work. Currently, I use `Makefile` to automatically call some passes via `opt`. But I should probably just call them from inside my program. I guess my current design has been affected by the fact that this tool started out as a `ModulePass` then was extended to become a standalone program. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @funnypigrun yes, you got what Alex wrote. At the IR level, in the same module and context, types have to have unique names. It's very C-like :)

Comment: @compor Well, I’m going to have to document that to help out my successors. Appreciate the help :D

Comment: Not sure I understand this. Is the problem that one type gets two different names with the same structure? Or are there two types in different contexts that are meant to have the same name? If the latter, then please disregard my comment above.

Comment: @arnt It's the latter case. I'm trying to load two mostly identical LLVM-IR codes. The problem was that I loaded them both with the same context. Thus, the type names in the second modules were considered to be conflicting with the first one. Thank you for your time.

Comment: In which case I think they actually are the same types, but you don't need them to be in the same context, so you can avoid the problem by using two different contexts. That's an excellent approach IMO, because every approach to a possible type conflict has serious drawbacks. Often, avoiding a problem is better than trying to solve it.

Comment: @arnt Yes. That is what I am going to do. Appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Do not use the same `LLVMContext` to read modules if they are **NOT** supposed to be in the same program.

---

**Long Answer:**

By reading multiple `Module`s with the same `LLVMContext`, you imply that those `Module`s are supposed to be within the same program.

So what happens is that, when there are multiple `Module`s that have the same type name , they get indexed in order to avoid conflict.

---

Thank you for all the help in the comments. :)